# Go HTTP Request with Basic Auth returning a 401 instead of a 301 redirect

Tags: redirect, curl, go

Using Go 1.5.1.

When I try to make a request to a site that automatically redirects to HTTPS using Basic Auth I would expect to get a 301 Redirect response, instead I get a 401.

```
package main

import "net/http"
import "log"

func main() {
    url := "http://aerolith.org/files"
    username := "cesar"
    password := "password"
    req, err := http.NewRequest("GET", url, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("error", err)
    }
    if username != "" || password != "" {
        req.SetBasicAuth(username, password)
        log.Println("[DEBUG] Set basic auth to", username, password)
    }
    cli := &http.Client{

    }
    resp, err := cli.Do(req)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Do error", err)
    }
    log.Println("[DEBUG] resp.Header", resp.Header)
    log.Println("[DEBUG] req.Header", req.Header)
    log.Println("[DEBUG] code", resp.StatusCode)

}
```

Note that curl returns a 301:

```
curl -vvv http://aerolith.org/files --user cesar:password
```

Any idea what could be going wrong?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A request to `http://aerolith.org/files` redirects to `https://aerolith.org/files` (note change from http to https).  A request to `https://aerolith.org/files` redirects to `https://aerolith.org/files/` (note addition of trailing /).

Curl does not follow redirects. Curl prints the 301 status for the redirect from `http://aerolith.org/files` to `https://aerolith.org/files/`.

The Go client follows the two redirects to `https://aerolith.org/files/`. The request to `https://aerolith.org/files/` returns with status 401 because the Go client does not propagate the authorization header through the redirects.

Requests to `https://aerolith.org/files/` from the Go client and Curl return status 200.

If you want to follow the redirects and auth successfully, set auth header in a [CheckRedirect](http://godoc.org/net/http#Client.CheckRedirect) function:

```
cli := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        if len(via) >= 10 {
            return errors.New("stopped after 10 redirects")
        }
        req.SetBasicAuth(username, password)
        return nil
    }}
resp, err := cli.Do(req)
```

If you want to match what Curl does, use a [transport](https://godoc.org/net/http#Transport) directly. The transport does not follow redirects.

```
resp, err := http.DefaultTransport.RoundTrip(req)
```

The application can also use the client [CheckRedirect](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client.CheckRedirect) function and a distinguished error to prevent redirects as shown in an answer to [How Can I Make the Go HTTP Client NOT Follow Redirects Automatically?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297520/how-can-i-make-the-go-http-client-not-follow-redirects-automatically/31296090#31296090). This technique seems to be somewhat popular, but is more complicated than using the transport directly.

```
redirectAttemptedError := errors.New("redirect")
cli := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        return redirectAttemptedError
    }}
resp, err := cli.Do(req)
if urlError, ok := err.(*url.Error); ok && urlError.Err == redirectAttemptedError {
    // ignore error from check redirect
    err = nil   
}
if err != nil {
    log.Println("Do error", err)
}
```