# Retain original URL in redirect error message

Tags: go

I'm trying to determine if a webpage exists on a particular website, by sending a `GET` request to the specific page. However, if the webpage doesn't exist, the website redirects the request to the home page.

To overcome this, I've implemented the redirection prevention, as stated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297520/how-can-i-make-the-go-http-client-not-follow-redirects-automatically), which looks something like

```golang
func RedirectCheck(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
    if req.Response.StatusCode == 200 {
        // no redirection occured
        return nil
    }
    // return error code
    return errors.New("webpage doesn't exist")
}
```

The redirection prevention works fine, but, if I made a get request to `https://someurl.com/page1`, the error message that I recieve is

```
Get "https://someurl.com": webpage doesn't exist
```

How do I configure the error message so that the original URL is retained in the error message?

The error message should then be

```
Get "https://someurl.com/page1": webpage doesn't exist
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [Client.CheckRedirect](https://godoc.org/net/http#Client.CheckRedirect) documentation says:

> As a special case, if CheckRedirect returns ErrUseLastResponse,then the most recent response is returned with its body unclosed, along with a nil error.

Fix by returning [ErrUseLastResponse](https://godoc.org/net/http#ErrUseLastResponse) from the function:

```
func RedirectCheck(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
    return http.ErroUseLastResponse
}
```