# http.NewRequest allow only one redirect

Tags: go

I came from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23297520/how-can-i-make-the-go-http-client-not-follow-redirects-automatically) and the answer works if I want no redirect at all:

```
client := &http.Client{
    CheckRedirect: func(req *http.Request, via []*http.Request) error {
        return http.ErrUseLastResponse
    },
}
```

But how can I allow exactly one redirect here?

Comment: Did you try checking the length of `via`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the [documentation](https://pkg.go.dev/net/http#Client) states:

> The arguments req and via are the upcoming request and the requests made already, oldest first.

So at the first redirect, `len(via)` will be 1. If you return error if `len(via)>1`, it should fail for additional requests.